# Simplest code to sort arrays in ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, dry

I usually do something like

```
array.sort{|a,b| a.something <=> b.something}
```

How should I DRY this up?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

use sort_by

`array.sort_by{|e| e.something}`

or

```
sort_lambda = lambda{|e| e.something}
array.sort_by(&sort_lambda)
```

With latter you can reuse sort_lambda in other sort_by statements

Answer (score 5):

In Rails, or rather with ActiveSupport, or in Ruby 1.9 (possibly 1.8.7, not sure) you can use the new short-cut hotness:

```
array.sort_by(&:something)
```

Note that `sort_by` has possibly expensive (and possibly beneficial: it depends on sort key complexity) side-effects: it generates and stores a temporary key-value pair for each item so that it can sort by your new key. See the [discussion in the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html) for more on this.

Comment: Yep, Ruby 1.8.7 has Symbol#to_proc.

Comment: It's trivial to implement: `def sort_on(property) sort_by &property end`

Answer (score 5):

+1 to both of Eimantas' suggestions, but I often have this come up in cases where I have a custom class that *always* sorts this way, like Albums that should sort case-insensitively, ignoring leading punctuation and the/a/an. For that use it's more efficient to calculate the sort value once, and then redefine <=> accordingly. E.g.:

```
class Album
 def sort_value
    @sv ||= @name.downcase.sub(/^\W*(the|an|a) /,"")
  end

  def <=>(other)
    sort_value <=> (other.sort_value rescue other)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered including Comparable in the class for a and b, and just calling sort?